# How to reverse Z3py Sequence?

Tags: z3, solver, z3py

I'm trying to make one Sequence equal antoher reversed. Here's the code:

```
s = Solver()

# declare sequences of integers
seq1 = Const('seq1', SeqSort(IntSort()))
seq2 = Const('seq2', SeqSort(IntSort()))


# assert the sequences have at least 3 elements
s.add(Length(seq1) >= 3)
s.add(Length(seq2) >= 3)

# here I don't know how to do it
s.add(seq1 == Reversed(seq2))


# get a model and print it:
if s.check() == sat:
   print(s.model())
```

How can I implement `Reversed` function?

The expected output is something like this:
`seq1 == [1, 2, 3] seq2 == [3, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible to write a `Reversed` function in z3py. However, such definitions tend to be fragile and not very friendly for proofs. That is, while you can define and use such functions, do *not* expect z3 to be able to prove arbitrary properties using such constructs. This is because such definitions are in general recursive, and to prove anything interesting about a recursive function you need to do induction. And SMT-solvers don't do induction out-of-the-box, at least not yet.

Having said that, here's how you'd code your `Reversed` function in z3py:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

# declare sequences of integers
seq1 = Const('seq1', SeqSort(IntSort()))
seq2 = Const('seq2', SeqSort(IntSort()))


# assert the sequences have at least 3 elements
s.add(Length(seq1) >= 3)
s.add(Length(seq2) >= 3)

Reversed = RecFunction('Reversed', SeqSort(IntSort()), SeqSort(IntSort()))
l = FreshConst(SeqSort(IntSort()))
RecAddDefinition( Reversed
                , [l]
                , If( Length(l) == 0
                    , l
                    , Concat(Reversed(Extract(l, 1, Length(l)-1)), Unit(l[0]))
                    )
                )

s.add(seq1 == Reversed(seq2))

# get a model and print it:
if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    print(m[seq1])
    print(m[seq2])
```

This prints:

```py
Concat(Unit(14), Concat(Unit(9), Unit(4)))
Concat(Unit(4), Concat(Unit(9), Unit(14)))
```

i.e, you get `[14, 9, 4]` and its reverse `[4, 9, 14]`.

Again, keep in mind that these constructs will mostly work well on ground-terms. Any property that needs induction will most likely lead z3 to give up and print `unknown`, or loop forever.